# How is the syntax to apply inputs in jupyter-notebook for windows (python3)?

Tags: python-3.x, input, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I have this code that runs on PyCharm without problems:

```
dia = input()
with open(f"FSC_{dia}.log", mode="r") as file, open(f"FSC_{dia}_saltopag.txt", mode="w") as wFile:
     for (...)
```

I'm trying to adapt it to jupyter-notebook - py3, but I got this syntax error:

[image: unicodeescape error]

I found in stackoverflow that I should type r before the path instead f to indicate it is a raw string, but when I set it as raw string it doesn't recognize me the input function:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-f4b2926639f7> in <module>
----> 1 with open(r"C:\Users\14122\PycharmProjects\LOGS_FSC\FSC_**{dia}**.log", mode='r') as file:
      2     counter = 0
      3     for f in file:
      4         counter = counter + 1
      5     print(counter)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\14122\\PycharmProjects\\LOGS_FSC\\**FSC_{dia}.log**'
```

I think it is related to the way I set this raw string, anyone knows about it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both `f` and `r` as arguments before your string to combine their effects.

```
with open(fr"C:\<etc>\FSC_{dial}.log", mode="r") as file:
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean string formatting?
See here:
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-examples

In particular, this example illustrates the use of named placeholders:

```
    'Coordinates: {latitude}, {longitude}'.format(latitude='37.24N', longitude='-115.81W'
```